# On the properties of covariance and kernel matrices

Tags: mixed-model, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, linear-algebra

I'm stumbling upon an example of a mixed model or a Gaussian Process, say:

- $Z \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, m \ge n$ ie random effect
- $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, p \ge 1$ ie fixed effects
- $K \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, K = ZZ^{T}$, ie. a linear kernel and Hermitian positive semidifinte
- $I \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ being the identity matrix
- $\Sigma \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \Sigma = \sigma_{1}^{2}K +  \sigma_{2}^{2}I$ where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix and Hermitian positive definite
- $P=X(X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}$ is a non-symmetric projection matrix
- $R = \Sigma^{-1}(I - P)$

Putting aside what we know about covariances etc, we can say $\Sigma$ is a kernel, since it's made up of adding two valid kernels.

I have the following questions:

1. What can we say about $R$, it is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and also a valid kernel itself?
2. What about $\Sigma^{-1}$, can we say this is a valid kernel too? This should be true, since it's just the precision matrix, and inverse of a hermitian is hermitian itself, right?
3. And finally, if 2 is true, for $A = \Sigma^{-1}K$ or $A = \Sigma^{-1}K_{2}$ where $K_{2}$ is another kernel, A is also a valid kernel hence symmetric positive semidefinite?

For 3, I'm assuming if 2 holds, then 3 is just the multiplication of two kernels hence holds true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:**

1. Correct, $\Sigma^{-1}(I-P)$, positive definite, would also be a kernel.
2. Correct, $\Sigma^{-1}$, positive definite is a valid kernel.
3. $\Sigma^{-1} K = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_1}I-\frac{\sigma^2_2}{\sigma^2_1}\Sigma^{-1}$ generally is not a valid kernel matrix. It is still symmetric, but not necessarily positive definite, whereas for a general kernel matrix $K_2$ even the symmetry of $\Sigma^{-1}K_2$ is not guaranteed.

**Reminder**:

The only requirement for a matrix to be useful as a kernel matrix is whether one can construct a valid [inner product map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) with it.

Restricting ourselves to vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, an inner product would be a map $x,y \to x^T K y$ with a matrix $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$

1. (*symmetry*) $ x^T K y = y^T K x$
2. (*linearity*) $ (\alpha x)^T K y = \alpha x^T K y $ and $ (x+z)^T K y = x^T K y + z^T K y$
3. (*positive-definiteness*) $x^T K x \geq 0 $ and zero only if the argument $x$ is zero (i.e. $x = \mathbf{0}$).

Wherefrom stem the requirements for positive-definiteness of kernel matrix $K$.

Comment: +1 cool! Which identity did you use for 3? Would you please include the derivation?

Comment: Couple of follow up questions before accepting the answer, 1- For $B = \Sigma^{-1}K_{2}$ the lack of guarantee comes from the fact that we don't have a way to guess the properties of $B$ without knowing if $\Sigma^{-1}$ and $K_{2}$ commute? Then can't we claim this for any multiplication of kernels? Because I see it is very common to multiply kernels and assume it's a valid kernel, ie. simple example would be polynomial degree 2 from linear etc. but of course there are many more scenarios?

Comment: And the second question is what can we say about $V=RK$? Based on 3, $V=aI - b\Sigma^{-1} - b\Sigma^{-1}X(X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}\Sigma^{-1} - a\Sigma^{-1}X(X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}$, $a = \frac{1}{\sigma^2_1}$ , $b=\frac{\sigma^2_2}{\sigma^2_1}$ hence non-symmetric?

Comment: Hey,
**a)** For 3 I just solved your definition of $\Sigma$ for $K$. Do you want me to develop that? 
Regarding your questions: 
**b)** when they speak of kernel multiplication, the multiplication of **kernel functions** $K(x,y)$ is meant, not the kernel matrices product. So either indeed you take two kernel matrices that commute or you may obtain a kernel matrix from two valid kernel matrices by means of Schur (aka Hadamard aka elementwise) product which again produces a positive-definite matrix.
**c)** $RK$ is not valid for the same reason, you cannot guarantee its positive-definiteness.

Comment: ah right! Thanks for reminding me this, I don't know why/when I started thinking about kernel products as matrix multiplication instead of Hadamard product.

Comment: Sorry one more question, Why $R$ is positive definite? I see the symmetry but where does the positive definite property come from?

Comment: You can decompose $\Sigma^{-1} = C C^T$ due to its symmetry and positive-definiteness. Then $a^T R a = a^TC ( I - C^T X (X^T C C^T X)^{-1} X^T C ) C^T a \geq 0$, because expression in the middle is again a projection (and therefore psd) matrix.